# Programatically setting the playback device for an application

Tags: c++, windows, wasapi

Does anyone know if it is possible to set the audio playback device programatically on Windows 7?
(I've seen quite a few posts on this but no 'good' answers). I don't really want to change the default playback device. E.g. If I have 2 sound cards and want the default to be sound card 1, I'd like my app to be able to use sound card 2. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do it using [IMMDeviceEnumerator Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Check out the Windows SDK core audio (winsapi) [samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316764%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for code.